# Maven woes: maven-clean-plugin not found in repository

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

**Sigh.**

Using maven 2.2.1, and suddenly it can't resolve the maven-clean-plugin. And really, how insane is it that a build tool requires a plugin for "clean"?

I tried syncing up my .m2 directory from another machine that works just fine, and I get the same results.

```
taproot:~/$ mvn clean package -DskipTests
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building CRM Webapp
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, package]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.2/maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.2' in repository maven.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.2/maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.2' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Specified destination directory cannot be created: /Users/armhold/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.2
Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss//org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.2/maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.2' in repository public jboss (http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/)
Downloading: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases//org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.2/maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.2' in repository jboss-my-rel (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/)
Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/maven2//org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.2/maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.2' from repository JBOSS (http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/): Specified destination directory cannot be created: /Users/armhold/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.2
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.2/maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.2' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Specified destination directory cannot be created: /Users/armhold/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin

Reason: POM 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.2

from the specified remote repositories:
  jboss-my-rel (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  maven.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2),
  JBOSS (http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/),
  public jboss (http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/)

 for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin
```

My pom looks like this:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>public jboss</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>jboss-my-rel</id>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>JBOSS</id>
        <name>JBoss Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

if you carefully read your error, you can find the answer there:

```
 Specified destination directory cannot be created:
 /Users/armhold/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.2
```

you dont have write access to that directory (or the user running maven process doesn't)

Comment: Ahh... In syncing up my .m2 I also copied over my settings.xml, which had a hard-coded path to a mac-style /Users home directory.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6):

Also I faced the similar issue.
But I found that was the proxy setting, which are used for our intranet, I did not put in Setting.xml. 
After putting it, it was boom boom...

```
    <proxy>
        <id>ABC</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <username>USER</username>
        <password>Password</password>
        <port>8080</port>
        <host>XXX.net</host>
        <nonProxyHosts>local.net,some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
```

Comment: I have a proxy connection and this is what worked for me.  I left all the irrelevant XML tags blank.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that you have a config or network problem that is stopping maven from getting to the net.

Comment: I tried turning iptables off, and that didn't help. I can 'wget' to the repos, so it doesn't *seem* to be a connectivity issue. Also, if my .m2 is synced up from a known-working machine, why would it even need to go offsite?

Answer (score 2):

I removed the `.m2/` directory tree.  I then did a `mvn clean` on my project and it downloaded everything again.

Answer (score -2):

Removing `.m2` folder is one option. You can also update your maven version to 3.x so it can resolve your maven plugins.